# Set Autosized label to center c#

Tags: c#, winforms, location, label, autosize

I have a Label in Windows Forms which has a specific text and size and has the property autosize set to true. I try to set his location to the center, but while using this code, it doesn't fit to the center of the form.

```
Label lab = new Label();
lab.Text = "blablabla";
lab.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 32);
lab.Autosize = true;
lab.Location = new Point(ClientSize.Width / 2 - lab.Width / 2, 0);
this.Controls.Add(lab);
```

Comment: For what plataform are you programming? (Webforms, WinForms)?

Comment: WinForms yeah, I will edit the post

Comment: Choose the correct tag instead of adding that info in post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's Winform then set `AutoSize` to `false` `lab.Autosize = false;` along with that set the `TextAlign` property to `MiddleCenter` `lab.TextAlign = MiddleCenter` and choose `Fill` for the docking property.